# Select row only on a max field

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
id  name    school  date
1   John    QVS 1/3/2000
1   John    RKS 1/4/2008
2   Sera    ACS 1/2/2009
2   Sera    WCS 1/4/2011
3   Jack    YUN 1/4/2014
3   Jack    KIL 1/3/2017
```

The name, school and date all came from different tables namely, name, school and date joined together with inner join.

i want to select only the row with the latest date. The result should be:

```
id  name    school  date
1   John    RKS 1/4/2008
2   Sera    WCS 1/4/2011
3   Jack    KIL 1/3/2017
```

Comment: What have you tried?  There are many ways to do this.

Comment: Give me then...i havent tried coz i dont know where to start from

Comment: the first table is not a dtabase table but a result from a joined query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`select * from table t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from table t2
    where t1.id = t2.id
      and t1.name = t2.name
      and t1.date < t2.date
)`

Comment: theres 3 tables combining to the first list above

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. I hope it will work for you.

```
SELECT
 tb1.id
,tb1.name
,tb1.school
,tb1.[date]
FROM 
yourTable tb1
where [date] IN
(
 SELECT MAX([date]) FROM yourTable tb2 WHERE tb1.id = tb2.id GROUP BY tb2.id
)
```

Comment: there is no tb1.school, its tb2.school and tb3.date

Comment: Can you give me all table structure?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Row_number`.
If you want all rows with latest date, then use `dense_rank` or `rank`

```
;with temp as
(
    select id, 
           name, 
           school, 
           [date],
           Row_number() over(partition by id order by [date] desc) as [Rn]
           -- rank()\dense_rank() to get all latest date.
    from yourTable
)
select     id, 
           name, 
           school, 
           [date]
from temp
where Rn = 1
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/YTH8889

Comment: i still want the value of date

Comment: you could select any columns you want, i use `select *` that includes `date` column already

Comment: some id still repeating...i just need the row for the recent available

Comment: How could it? See my example

Comment: the values from the first table is a result of my query...three tables join together by inner join....so name, school, and date are three different tables..please strat from there

Comment: You need to handle it yourself. my `yourTable` can be your join query, or you can use 2 temp table.....